# mysql get the last two characters of a column value where value length is equal to X

Tags: php, mysql

I need to get the last two characters of a column value on my `mysql` database but the length of the value(string) varies i tried below query but sometimes it gives me only one character, how can i ensure that it only gets the last two character when the string length is = X?

```
"SELECT SUBSTRING(BOARDTYPE, length(BOARDTYPE) -1 , 3) as brd"
```

I also tried below.

```
"SELECT RIGHT(BOARDTYPE, 2) as brd"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do length minus one it will give you last 2 chars always

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(BOARDTYPE, length(BOARDTYPE) -1 ) as brd
```

Comment: Thanks looks like my data is all messed up, does the length count spaces?

Comment: Yes it counts the spaces between words, but ignores trailing spaces

Answer (score 1):

Substring needs 3 parameters. You can try 
SELECT SUBSTRING(BOARDTYPE, length(BOARDTYPE) -1 , 2) as brd

Comment: you can also use a FROM keyword: select SUBSTRING(BOARDTYPE from  length(BOARDTYPE) -1) as brd

Comment: Thanks, looks like the length cannot capture the white spaces from the value.